# Android Studio Can I save the javadoc comments to an external file

Tags: android-studio, external, javadoc

Is it possible to write javadoc  comments in a seperate file.

My usual method for writing comments is like below

```
/**
*@param name person name
*/
private void testMethod(String name) {
    //something to do...
}
```

Is it possible to move all these embedded comments to a external file(s) that i can reference.It should still show the popup on mouse-over.

Comment: why the down vote, i just wanted to know if it is not possible , or just bad practice.

Comment: @Henry i accept your explanation, could you put in as an answer so that i can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The main idea behind Javadoc is to keep code and documentation together to increase the likelihood that they stay in sync.